# Finding Revenue Function and Max Revenue

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, finance

Studying for a midterm.

The demand function for a manufacture's product is $p=1000-\frac1{80} q$

Where $p$ is the
price (in dollars) per unit when $q$ units are demanded (per week) by consumers. Answer
the following questions.

1) Write the Revenue function $R(q)$ in terms of $q$.

2) Find the level of production that will maximize revenue.

3)Suppose there is a fixed cost of  $174500, to set up the manufacture and a producing cost of 125 dollars per unit. Find the break even quantities.

First: To find the revenue function.

I know that Revenue=$p*q$ so:

$$R(q)=p*q$$

$$p=1000-\frac1{80}q$$

$$R(q)=(1000-\frac1{80}q)*q$$

$$=1000q-\frac1{80}q^2$$

I believe this is right.

Now to find the level of production to maxime revenue we must find the first derivative of the revenue function.

$$R'(q)=1000-2(\frac1{80}q)$$
$$2(\frac1{80}q)=1000$$
$$\frac1{80}q=500$$
$$q=40000$$
Input this into our demand function:

$$p=1000-\frac1{80}40000$$
$$p=500$$

Now I don't know if this is right, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now I'm not sure how to find the break even quantities, I would appreciate help, at least to get me started.

Cheers.

Comment: For the breakeven point, you will have to solve a quadratic, as mentioned in an answer. Probably you will use the Quadratic Formula, though in fact one can factor. There will be two positive roots. The smaller one is the breakeven point. It will be a very "round" number.

Comment: How are there 60k views but only 4 upvotes......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is correct.  To find the break even quantities, you need to find where the Revenue function is equal to the cost function.  Your cost function is $C(q)=174500+125q$.

Comment: I gave it a shot and I end up with $0=q^2-70000q+1396000$, although this is unfactorable.

Comment: @Unknown You don't need to factor.  The quadratic formula will give you your answers.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand, can you be more specific?

Comment: Do I just input 40000 in place of q?

Comment: @Unknown The quadratic formula is a way to solve $0=q^2-70000q+1396000$.

Comment: Nevermind. Brain fart. I've solved them. It's $q=-70000+\frac{\sqrt{-70000^2-4*1396000}}2$ and

 $q=-70000-\frac{\sqrt{-70000^2-4*1396000}}2$

Which are 69800 and 20 respectively.

Comment: @Unknown You must divide $-70000$ by $2$ as well.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after my post.