# revenue function

Tags: calculus

It is determined that $q$ units of a commodity can be sold when the price is $p$ hundred dollars per unit, where:

$$
q(p)= 1000\cdot(p+2)e^{-p}
$$

**Questions:**

> a) For what price $p$ is revenue $R$ maximized?
>
> b) What is the maximum revenue?

Comment: There are simmilar questions already: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521898/finding-revenue-function-and-max-revenue

Comment: Hint: The revenue $R(p)$ when the price is $p$ is given by
$R(p)=1000p(p+2)e^{-p}$.
We wish to maximize $R(p)$.   
We have $R'(p)=1000(p^2+2p)(-e^{-p})+1000e^{-p}(2p+2)=1000e^{-p}(2-p^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revenue function is

$$
R(p) = p\cdot q = 1000p(p+2)\exp(-p)
$$

The revenue is maximized when $R^\prime (p)=0$, that is,

$$
-1000(p^2 - 2)\exp(-p)=0
$$

Since $\exp(-p)$ will never vanish completely, the revenue is maximized when $p=\sqrt{2}$, as the price cannot be negative.

You may also want to conduct a second derivative test to ensure that it is indeed the (local) maximum.

Comment: when you multiply the equation by p does e^-p also get multiplied by p. shouldn't it be pe^-p?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to first take (natural) logarithms, which yields

$$\log p +\log 1000 + \log (p+2) -p$$

Maximizing with respect to $p$ yields $1/p+1/(p+2)-1=0$.  Solve for $p$, then stick it into $pq(p)$ to obtain the answer to part b.